# how to play background music while recording voice?

Tags: iphone, audio, audio-recording

friends

Now I'm developing iPhone Recorder App.

I can easily record my voice with sample code.

I want to record background music with my voice.

For example,When I click "Record" button,background music plays
Then I sing a song.

In this case,I should record background music  with my voice.

But,If I did like that,I can't record anything.

What's wrong?

To do this,what should I do?

Please help me..

Thanks.

Comment: have you done this? I want to implement same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with programming for the iPhone but I can imagine there would be a limitation to what you like to achieve IF you intend to make this work without using headphones/headset. It just might be that the OS wont let you play music and record at the same time because the recording would result in an echo because of the background music.

That said, I'm sure an experienced iPhone programmer is able to tell you exactly how this would work.

Good luck and I hope my suggestion helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

friends

I solved this problem by using OpenAL.

Thanks for all your effet.

Comment: How did u solved ur problem can u share a sample here as m facing the same problem

Comment: please provide any link for your solution.. I am a newbie to openAL and I am in the same situation as you were!